# What is the easiest way to add an element to html through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

It seems there are many ways to do this, however, none of them make sense to me. If anyone can give me an example of how to add a tag and edit its attributes (no document.write mess) that works in all common browsers  **BUT**  IE, that would be great.

 EDIT 
I simply do not care if it works in IE or not. If it does, fine but I dislike IE so much anyway I will just ask people to change browsers since other stuff on the page I am creating does not work in IE.

Comment: A requirement is that it must fail in IE??

Comment: Well if you were willing to try jquery, it has an append method that would do this

Comment: All IE version or a specific version?

Comment: Judging from the answers, nobody read the whole question...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you want it to work in IE?

Comment: @Charlie, maybe its the clients requirements :)

Comment: Perhaps he meant to say that the requirement is that it work in all common browsers, except that he doesn't care whether it works in IE or not? That's somewhat my case, except that I've told those who want to use what I'm doing that I'm only supporting it in Firefox.

Comment: I would just not like it to have to work in IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the easiest example of how to create a `<div>` element and add it to the layout.

```
var el = document.createElement("div");   // creating element
el.setAttribute("class", "myClass");      // setting attribute "class"
el.innerHTML = "Text";                    // adding text inside the element
document.body.appendChild(el);​            // appending new element to page body
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XVaqY/

To make it not working in IE add any browser check. Something [like that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
function isIE() {
    return (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer");
}
```

Comment: @Esailija Yes, I haven't noticed that condition. Sounds weird though.

Comment: `window.XMLHttpRequest` is true from IE7 ;) (or the function should be named `isIE6AndOlder()`)

Comment: @F.Calderan Wow, IE progresses! I'm not an expert in IE detection. Let the OP to choose what algorithm is better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of adding a DIV with javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/wp2Re/

```
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>Javascript Create Div Element Dynamically</title>  
    <style type="text/css">  
        .dynamicDiv {  
            width: 200px;  
            height: 100px;  
            border: solid 1px #c0c0c0;  
            background-color: #e1e1e1;  
            font-size: 11px;  
            font-family: verdana;  
            color: #000;  
            padding: 5px;  
        }  
    </style>  

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  

        function createDiv() { 
            var divTag = document.createElement("div"); 

            divTag.id = "div1"; 

            divTag.setAttribute("align", "center"); 

            divTag.style.margin = "0px auto"; 

            divTag.className = "dynamicDiv"; 

            divTag.innerHTML = "This HTML Div tag created "  
                                + "using Javascript DOM dynamically."; 

            document.body.appendChild(divTag); 
        } 
    </script>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <p align="center">  
        <b>Click this button to create div element dynamically:</b>  
        <input id="btn1"   
                type="button"   
                value="create div"   
                onclick="createDiv();" />  
    </p>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you create the element with [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM%3adocument.createElement) and save it to a variable. At this point it is not in the DOM yet.
Then, change its attributes as much as you like, and then insert it into the DOM at any point you like. In my example, it will insert a `DIV` element with the `id` of `elementid` into the end of the `body` tag.

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
newDiv.id = "elementid";
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few methods to add content to the DOM:

Using the W3C recommended approach:

```
var heading = document.createElement("h1");
heading.createTextNode("Foobar");
heading.className = "semantic-class-name-goes-here";
heading.setAttribute("aria-something-here", "bar");
```

Using innerHTML:

```
document
    .innerHTML("<h1 class='semantic-class-name-goes-here' aria-something-here='bar'>Foobar</h1>");
```

Using jQuery:

```
var heading = $("h1")
    .addClass("semantic-class-name-goes-here")
    .attr("aria-something-here", "bar");

$(document).append(heading);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to exclude all IE versions, using this trick from [webreflection blog](http://webreflection.blogspot.it/2009/01/32-bytes-to-know-if-your-browser-is-ie.html) you could do

```
if (!(!+"\v1")) {
   var el = document.createElement("div");    
   ...
   document.body.appendChild(el);
}
```

Alternatively, another condition to detect IE could also be

```
if (!top.execScript) { ... }
```

or even

```
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/!1;
if (isIE) { ... }
```

but to be honest they're so hacky for me.
Anyway, if you specify the technical reason for excluding IE and tell us what kind of functionality are you trying to accomplish, probably it's possibile to give you a safer way to do this task, based on a specific IE limit (feature dection is better than browser sniffing).